# How to determine current number of iteration in callback (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is the code for nodejs. If I log value of variable "i" in response.on("end") callback, then it prints number "2" three times. I don't get why.

```
var http = require('http'),
        urls = [],
        requestsDone  = 0,
        result = [];

    for (var i in process.argv) {
        if (i > 1) {
            urls.push(process.argv[i]);
        }
    }

    for (var i in urls) {

        var nextUrl = urls[i];
        http.get(nextUrl, function(response){
            var allData = '';
            response.on("data", function(data){
                allData += data;
            });

            response.on("end", function(){
                console.log(i);
                result[requestsDone] = allData;
                requestsDone +=1;
                if (requestsDone == 3) {
                    console.log(result.join('\n'));
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `forEach` (instead of `for (var i in urls)`), which creates a new scope:

```
urls.forEach(function(nextUrl, i) {
  http.get(nextUrl, function(response) {
    ...
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is because the `http.get` call is asynchronous.

The iterating `for` loop goes from `0` to `urls.length` in a blink of an eye as it is not held up by asynchronous code. On the other hand the code that is executed inside the event `end` callback is called long after the iterator has iterated from `0` to `urls.length` so any call to `console.log(i)` will print its final value as its reached that value well before the log statement is executed.

**robertkelp**'s solution is sensible, creating a new closure (scope) is the way to go here.

Theres a simple example to demonstrate what you are seeing:

```
var array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
for(i in array) {
    setTimeout(function() { //simulating the async nature of the http.get call
        console.log(array[i], i);
    }, 1000); 
}
```

That will print `9 9` 10 times, that's what you are seeing.

Creating a scope and passing `i` will ensure the value of `i` is captured, here is the simplest approach:

```
var array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

function log(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(array[i], i);
    }, 1000); 
}

for(i in array) {
    log(i); //creating a new scope and capturing the value of i
}
```

and a more mature approach (using the same forEach iterator as **robertkelp** suggests)

```
var array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

array.forEach(function(number, i) { //forEach creates a new scope implicitly for you
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(number, i);
    },1000);
});
```

**Protip:** When diagnosing things like this I construct what I call a 'bench test'. It's where you recreate a very small program that recreates the environment under which you are observing the anomaly but with no extraneous code. The basic for loop with a timeout is a good example that I use frequently to experiment with asynchronous code.